Page Layout with Image in the bottom
This is a layout question similar to Position an image on a page
Obvious solution did not work
\useMPlibrary[dum]
\showframe
\starttext

\setuplayout[bottomthird]
  [bottom=0pt,
   bottomdistance=0pt,
   footer=0pt,
   footerdistance=0pt
  ]

\samplefile{ward}

\startplacefloat
  []
  [location={left,nonumber}]
  \startcombination
    [nx=1,
     ny=3,
     after={\blank[2*big]}]
    {\externalfigure[dummy][width=1.5in]}{}
    {\externalfigure[dummy][width=1.5in]}{}
    {\externalfigure[dummy][width=1.5in]}{}
  \stopcombination
  \blank[6*big]% Added to keep the "columns"
\stopplacefloat

\blank[enable]

\startitemize[n]
  \startitem
    \samplefile{ward}
  \stopitem
  \startitem
    \samplefile{ward}
  \stopitem
  \startitem
    \samplefile{ward}
  \stopitem
\stopitemize

\startplacefloat
  []
  [location={force,nonumber}]
  \externalfigure
    [dummy]
    [width=\textwidth,
     height=0.3\textheight]
\stopplacefloat

\setuplayout[reset]

\stoptext



There still footer and it does not push the image all the way to the page edge

Am I missing some layout settings ?

The ConTeXt garden is helpful here. In particular the image. We can use \dimexpr to subtract the relevant heights from \paperheight.
Your \setuplayout[reset] comes to early. Add \page[yes] before it.
Also, for the picture to really go down, it might be easier to use \vfill to push it down (and then one can wonder if you really need the figure environment).
So, perhaps something like this:
\useMPlibrary[dum]
\showframe

\definelayout
  [bottomthird]
  [bottom=0pt,
   bottomspace=0pt,
   bottomdistance=0pt,
   footer=0pt,
   footerdistance=0pt,
   height=\dimexpr\paperheight-\topheight-\headerheight-\headerdistance\relax]


\starttext

\setuplayout
  [bottomthird]

\samplefile{ward}

\startplacefloat
  []
  [location={left,nonumber}]
  \startcombination
    [nx=1,
     ny=3,
     after={\blank[2*big]}]
    {\externalfigure[dummy][width=1.5in]}{}
    {\externalfigure[dummy][width=1.5in]}{}
    {\externalfigure[dummy][width=1.5in]}{}
  \stopcombination
  \blank[6*big]% Added to keep the "columns"
\stopplacefloat

\blank[enable]

\startitemize[n]
  \startitem
    \samplefile{ward}
  \stopitem
  \startitem
    \samplefile{ward}
  \stopitem
  \startitem
    \samplefile{ward}
  \stopitem
\stopitemize

\vfill

\startplacefloat
  []
  [location={force,nonumber}]
  \externalfigure
    [dummy]
    [width=\textwidth,
     height=0.3\textheight]
\stopplacefloat

\vkern-\strutdp

\page[yes]

\setuplayout[reset]

\samplefile{ward}

\stoptext

The output here is like this:

Maybe for this kind of page, a layer is easier than changing the layout?

In theory, we should be able to use location={bottom, low, footer} and get your desired result, but unfortunately location=footer only works with location=page.
Instead, we can define a new float location infooter that places its contents in the footer of the page:
%% Define a new float method
\installfloatmethod{singlecolumn}{infooter}{%
    \insert\namedinsertionnumber{bottomfloat}{%
        \vfill%
        \vbox{%
            \doplacefloatbox%
            \unskip%
            \vskip-\footerheight%
        }%
    }%
}

\appendtoks%
    \ifdim\insertheights>\zeropoint\relax%
        \setupfooter[state=empty]%
    \fi%
\to \beforeeverypage

\insertlimit\namedinsertionnumber{bottomfloat}\zeropoint

%% Disable the figure captions
\setupcaptions[figure][location=none]

%% Additional formatting just for this demonstration (ignore this section)
\useMPlibrary[dum]
\setupindenting[yes, big]
\showframe
\definecolor[layout:page][s=1]

\setuptexts[header]        [Top Center]
\setuptexts[footer]        [Bottom Center]
\setuptexts[header][text]  [Top Left]   [Top Right]
\setuptexts[header][margin][TL Margin]  [TR Margin]
\setuptexts[text]  [margin][L Margin]   [R Margin]
\setuptexts[footer][margin][BL Margin]  [BR Margin]
\setuptexts[footer][text]  [Bottom Left][Bottom Right]

\setuppapersize[A4][A2]
\setuppaper[nx=2,ny=2]
\setuparranging[XY]

%% Demonstration
\starttext
    \startplacefigure[location=infooter]
        \externalfigure[dummy][width=\textwidth, height=0.3\textheight]
    \stopplacefigure

    \dorecurse{8}{\samplefile{knuth}}

    \dorecurse{2}{
        \startplacefigure[location=infooter]
            \externalfigure[dummy][width=\textwidth, height=0.3\textheight]
        \stopplacefigure
    }

    \dorecurse{3}{\samplefile{knuth}}
\stoptext


Or, using your sample code:
%% Copied from the sample code above
\installfloatmethod{singlecolumn}{infooter}{%
    \insert\namedinsertionnumber{bottomfloat}{%
        \vfill%
        \vbox{%
            \doplacefloatbox%
            \unskip%
            \vskip-\footerheight%
        }%
    }%
}

\appendtoks%
    \ifdim\insertheights>\zeropoint\relax%
        \setupfooter[state=empty]%
    \fi%
\to \beforeeverypage

\insertlimit\namedinsertionnumber{bottomfloat}\zeropoint

%% Copied from the code in the question
\useMPlibrary[dum]
\showframe
\starttext

\setuplayout[bottomthird]
  [bottom=0pt,
   bottomdistance=0pt,
   footer=0pt,
   footerdistance=0pt
  ]

\samplefile{ward}

\startplacefloat
  []
  [location={left,nonumber}]
  \startcombination
    [nx=1,
     ny=3,
     after={\blank[2*big]}]
    {\externalfigure[dummy][width=1.5in]}{}
    {\externalfigure[dummy][width=1.5in]}{}
    {\externalfigure[dummy][width=1.5in]}{}
  \stopcombination
  \blank[6*big]% Added to keep the "columns"
\stopplacefloat

\blank[enable]

\startitemize[n]
  \startitem
    \samplefile{ward}
  \stopitem
  \startitem
    \samplefile{ward}
  \stopitem
  \startitem
    \samplefile{ward}
  \stopitem
\stopitemize

\startplacefloat
  []
  [location={infooter,nonumber}] %% <- CHANGED!
  \externalfigure
    [dummy]
    [width=\textwidth,
     height=0.3\textheight]
\stopplacefloat

\setuplayout[reset]

\stoptext


